# MS DOS/WIN BATCH CMD: set /a "x=1%%y-100", i don't understand what this modulo is doing with y

Tags: batch-file, cmd, set, modulo

I'm working with a WIN/DOS batch script and it uses the example, problem is i don't get what it's doing at all, maybe because it's Microsoft...

What's happening here to x & y?  It seems to result in x=y.  Can someone explain it to me in some sort of pedantic style?

```
set /a "x=1%%y-100"
```

Comment: please post the context; I assume, it's inside a `for`statement?

Comment: yes, sorry i'm guessing you ask because that changes the context, or the variable syntax?

Comment: yes, exactly. Aaacini already described it in his answer.

Comment: there's no `set /a` in DOS. [The Windows cmd.exe is not DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Answer (score 1):

```
set /a "x=1%%y-100"
```

This type of operations are usually used to convert to number a string that may have a left zero, like days or months numbers taken from a %date% value, because if the number is 08 or 09, it is treated as an illegal octal number. For example:

```
set anyDate=09/08/1954
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%x in ("%anyDate%") do (
   echo Month: %%x, Day: %%y, Year: %%z
)
```

Previous trick first join a "1" before the day number, so `1%%y` becomes `108`, and then subtract 100 from it, so x=8 (day number).

Comment: So, the %% is not a modulo operation, instead it is a concatenation operation?

Comment: er rather it's part of the variable syntax only?

Comment: Lol, so in this case if it was meant to be modulo the syntax would have been 1%%%%y or 1%%%y, in a batch file?

Comment: Even if it works without spaces, I would stronlgy recommend to enclose the modulo operator into spaces to keep it readable. Compare `%x%%%%y%` with `%x% %% %y%` (keep your eyes open, this is not the ugliest thing in batch...)